# Problem with Contour Plot in a Manipulate expression

Tags: plotting

I am trying to get a contour plot for `1 - (Sin^2[2*x])*(Sin^2[1.27*400*y]) == c` where `c` goes from 0 to 1.. The range for `x` and `y` are `{x, 0.00174533, 0.20944}` and `{y, 0.002, 0.003}`, respectively.

This is my code.

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[
    1 - (Sin^2)[2*12]*(Sin^2)[1.27*4000*x] == c, 
    {x, 0.00174533, 0.20944}, {y, 0.002, 0.003}], 
  {c, 0, 1}]
```

I see nothing in plot viewport.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[1 - (Sin^2)[2*12]*(Sin^2)[1.27*4000*x] == c, {x, 0.00174533, 0.20944}, {y, 0.002, 0.003}],
 {c, 0, 1}
 ]

Comment: `Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  1 - Sin[2*12]^2*Sin[1.27*4000*x]^2 == c, {x, 0.00174533, 
   0.20944}, {y, 0.002, 0.003}], {c, 0, 1}]` is that?

Comment: You have several syntactic errors in your code. It makes no sense to use `Sin^2`, for instance. Moreover, you should simplify your code to a minimal example. Do you really need all those digits in the limits of `x` and `y`? No. Do you need to write `1.27*4000*x` instead of multiplying those two numbers first? No. Do you need `2*12` rather than `24`? No. Moreover, even with the syntactic errors your code does not match your equation. Please be *far* more careful when posting a question so we can help you--and want to.